# How to handle 5 million users? ASP.NET Identity

Tags: asp.net, identity

I am running a ASP.NET mvc5 app which currently has 5 million users. It is hosted in the Azure cloud. For the authentication I use the Asp.Net Identity for EntityFramework.

However, the more users I get, the slower the register function becomes. I tried scaling the database, but the results are still the same. It takes around 6-7 seconds for a new user to register.

Also I tried searching how I can improve the performance of the identity system, but I couldn't really find anything relevant.

I would really like to hear if somebody has some idea how can I improve the performance of it.

UPDATE: I have indexes on the fields that I am searching on, also, the database subscription that I have chosen in Azure is P3 SQL database with 200 DTUs.

I profiled the DB and I found a suspicious select query.
I deleted some of the projections and replaced them with "...." so it doesn't get too long and you can see what is the query about.

```
SELECT 
    [UnionAll2].[Gender] AS [C1], 
    ....
    [UnionAll2].[UserName] AS [C27], 
    [UnionAll2].[C1] AS [C28], 
    [UnionAll2].[UserId] AS [C29], 
    [UnionAll2].[RoleId] AS [C30], 
    [UnionAll2].[UserId1] AS [C31], 
    [UnionAll2].[C2] AS [C32], 
    [UnionAll2].[C3] AS [C33], 
    [UnionAll2].[C4] AS [C34], 
    [UnionAll2].[C5] AS [C35], 
    [UnionAll2].[C6] AS [C36], 
    [UnionAll2].[C7] AS [C37], 
    [UnionAll2].[C8] AS [C38], 
    [UnionAll2].[C9] AS [C39]
    FROM  (SELECT 
        CASE WHEN ([Extent2].[UserId] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) ELSE 1 END AS [C1], 
        [Limit1].[Gender] AS [Gender], 
        ....
        [Limit1].[UserName] AS [UserName], 
        [Extent2].[UserId] AS [UserId], 
        [Extent2].[RoleId] AS [RoleId], 
        [Extent2].[UserId] AS [UserId1], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C2], 
        CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C3], 
        CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C4], 
        CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C5], 
        CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C6], 
        CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C7], 
        CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C8], 
        CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C9]
        FROM   (SELECT TOP (1) 
            [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
            ....
            [Extent1].[UserName] AS [UserName]
            FROM [dbo].[Users] AS [Extent1]
            WHERE ((UPPER([Extent1].[UserName])) = (UPPER(@p__linq__0))) OR ((UPPER([Extent1].[UserName]) IS NULL) AND (UPPER(@p__linq__0) IS NULL)) ) AS [Limit1]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[UserRoles] AS [Extent2] ON [Limit1].[Id] = [Extent2].[UserId]
    UNION ALL
        SELECT 
        2 AS [C1], 
        [Limit2].[Gender] AS [Gender], 
        ....
        [Limit2].[UserName] AS [UserName], 
        CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C2], 
        CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C3], 
        CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C4], 
        [Extent4].[Id] AS [Id1], 
        [Extent4].[UserId] AS [UserId], 
        [Extent4].[ClaimType] AS [ClaimType], 
        [Extent4].[ClaimValue] AS [ClaimValue], 
        CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C5], 
        CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C6], 
        CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C7], 
        CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C8]
        FROM   (SELECT TOP (1) 
            [Extent3].[Id] AS [Id], 
            ....
            [Extent3].[UserName] AS [UserName]
            FROM [dbo].[Users] AS [Extent3]
            WHERE ((UPPER([Extent3].[UserName])) = (UPPER(@p__linq__0))) OR ((UPPER([Extent3].[UserName]) IS NULL) AND (UPPER(@p__linq__0) IS NULL)) ) AS [Limit2]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[UserClaims] AS [Extent4] ON [Limit2].[Id] = [Extent4].[UserId]
    UNION ALL
        SELECT 
        3 AS [C1], 
        [Limit3].[Gender] AS [Gender], 
        ....
        [Limit3].[UserName] AS [UserName], 
        CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C2], 
        CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C3], 
        CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C4], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C5], 
        CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C6], 
        CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C7], 
        CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C8], 
        [Extent6].[LoginProvider] AS [LoginProvider], 
        [Extent6].[ProviderKey] AS [ProviderKey], 
        [Extent6].[UserId] AS [UserId], 
        [Extent6].[UserId] AS [UserId1]
        FROM   (SELECT TOP (1) 
            [Extent5].[Id] AS [Id], 
            ....
            [Extent5].[UserName] AS [UserName]
            FROM [dbo].[Users] AS [Extent5]
            WHERE ((UPPER([Extent5].[UserName])) = (UPPER(@p__linq__0))) OR ((UPPER([Extent5].[UserName]) IS NULL) AND (UPPER(@p__linq__0) IS NULL)) ) AS [Limit3]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[UserLogins] AS [Extent6] ON [Limit3].[Id] = [Extent6].[UserId]) AS [UnionAll2]
    ORDER BY [UnionAll2].[Id] ASC, [UnionAll2].[C1] ASC
```

My EntityFramework User POCO class

```
    public class User : IdentityUser
    {
        [Index]
        public DateTime Created { get; set; }
        [Index(IsUnique = true), MaxLength(255)]
        public override string Email { get; set; }
        public string Firstname { get; set; }
        public string Lastname { get; set; }
        [Index]
        public GenderType Gender { get; set; }
        [Index]
        public DateTime? Birthdate { get; set; }
        [Index, MaxLength(2)]
        public string Country { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(2)]
        public string Language { get; set; }
        [Index, MaxLength(256)]
        public string Referral { get; set; }
        public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
        [Index]
        public UserIdentityStatus IdentityConfirmed { get; set; }
        [Index]
        public DateTime? Deleted { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Reward> Ads { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Thought> Thoughts { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Achievement> Achievements { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Subscription> Subscriptions { get; set; }
        public DateTime? TutorialShown { get; set; }
        [Index]
        public DateTime? LastActivity { get; set; }
        [Index]
        public DateTime? LastBulkEmail { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: I suggest to find if the entity framework make the delay, or the asp.net its self. And then move to the next step...

Comment: As far as I can see the UserManager.CreateAsync() is the method that slows down everything...

Comment: I have the same issue even with a small AspNetUsers table with just 45,000 users. Every time someone logs in this query runs and it has a high read count because the use of UPPER is forcing it to perform an index scan instead of a seek. The server is a bit low power and the query often exceeds a 30 second timeout. I will try the suggested index in the accepted answer.

Comment: I use `UserManager.FindByName(User.Identity.GetUserName())` all the time, this issue killed our performance (~50k users).  To quote http://www.slideshare.net/oazabir/scaling-aspnet-websites-to-millions-of-users (Feb 2012, slide 18): "DO NOT use Email or UserName fields in WHERE clause.  They are not part of the index instead LoweredUserName and LoweredEmail in conjunction with ApplicationID".  As Bryan points out, at least they have fixed now :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think I have solution for you. I have made another tests and the second option - index on computed column works. Here are steps in sql code, you can probably do the same using EF annotations.

1. Create computed column on table users as upper(username):

   alter table users add upper_username as upper(username)
2. Create index on that column:

   create index ix2 on a_upload(upper_username)

Thats all. The EF select will still use UPPER, but MS SQL optimizer should be able to use this index as it has the same definition as the function in where clause.

Here are test results on my PC:

test sql: select field001 from a_upload where upper(field001)='10'

BEFORE (SCAN means that the engine has to read all records one by one)

[image: BEFORE]

AFTER CREATING THE INDEX on functional column (SEEK=engine will utilize index)

[image]

Dont get confuzed that even in the BEFORE scenario, sql engine is using index (ix1). It is only because I am selecting only "field001" and the optimizer knows, that it is contained not only in the table but in the index too. And index has less bytes than whole table. But it does not mean that the system utilized index, it has to compute upper() for every row on each select anyway.

Comment: More info on dealing with functional indexes when migration from Oracle to MS SQL: http://www.sqlines.com/oracle/function_based_indexes

Comment: wow it works as supposed. thank you very much for the solution, i love it

Comment: This post on GitHub indicates that this issue is fixed in ASP.NET Identity 3.0 and confirms that the proposed solution here is suitable for anyone running an earlier version. https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/issues/351

Comment: This was truly awesome. Congrats! Very cool solution, because EF and ASPNET ID is pretty much a closed box so that query seems to be very deep within ASPNET ID. Thats why I dont like EF nor ASPNET ID, too opaque.

Comment: Note: If you're using the `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.AspNetCoreCompat` package (as I am) then this same solution works. I'm using identity primarily in .NET5 (a ASPNET Core project) but I still have a .NET Framework 4.x project that needs to access my users. Hence my usage of the CoreCompat package. Slight variation is that I *already* have a `NormalizedUserName` field in my table (AspNetUsers for Identity Core) so I used this for my computed column `ALTER TABLE dbo.AspNetUsers ADD NormalizedUserName_Computed AS UPPER(Username);`. Then create the index and boom!

Answer (score 5):

While I had to replace the userId guid with an int, I created a CustomUserStore. In this UserStore you can simply overwrite the FindByNameAsync:

```
public class CustomUserStore<TUser> : UserStore<TUser, CustomRole, int, CustomUserLogin, CustomUserRole, CustomUserClaim> where TUser : MyUser
{
    public CustomUserStore(MyDbContext context) : base(context) { }

    public override Task<TUser> FindByNameAsync(string userName)
    {
        return this.GetUserAggregateAsync(u => u.UserName.Equals(userName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
    }
}
```

This results in a query without UPPER().

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. I think this is the cleanest way to get to the correct result. I tried this and verified it does indeed create a query without the UPPER. Also, to add to this. FindByEmailAsync should also be updated as it too uses UPPER. My ID is a string, but that does not use UPPER, so FindByIdAsync does not need to be updated.

Comment: Thank you. This is the cleanest solution of the two.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this query is probably the problem. This is why I don't like SQL frameworks.

The problem is here:

```
WHERE 
((UPPER([Extent3].[UserName])) = (UPPER(@p__linq__0)))
```

The right side is constant and the left side "upper(username)" is SQL engine trying to find  somewhere. Index on simple "username" is useless, because it contains simple "username" and not upper(username) values. SQL engine has to calculate upper(username) for all 5 millions lines EVERYTIME you add new user and then find the corresponding value. 7 seconds...

You need to create such index:

```
create index ix_name on Users(upper(UserName))
```

Such index will be used automatically by sql engine. But I am afraid, that MS SQL will not allow you to do it without adding computed column (and it is useless for your purpose, because you can not force EF to use another column for username value).

The other option is to force Identity framework not to use UPPER function. But I don't know how.

By the way, I am really surprised to find this type of code in such important package - entity framework. This "searching functional value in index" is on of the basic mistakes when writing efficient sql code.

And one more comment: This everything should have been done by the framework, it is responsible for correct handling of "username" column. It is a bug, this advice is only workaround.

Comment: I tried what you told me and the results were as expected, it would continue to use the UPPER function...

I wonder how nobody bumped into this problem before. I guess it's not a very good idea to user EF for enterprise solutions. But it's not even enterprise. It's like 5 million users, I could imagine if I had to deal with 20...

Comment: EF gives SQL functionality to developers, who are not familiar with SQL, it creates "database-like" layer. For big application I would recommend to hire someone who will create true database layer, it will be always more efficient. In applications with 5M users you dont have to think ONLY about what data to access, but also HOW to access them (like in your problem). And here the EF is very weak.

Comment: You could try the second option with computed column, here is more detailed description: http://www.sqlines.com/oracle/function_based_indexes

Answer (score 2):

Try to get the exact SQL command from some Azure audit tool and write it to the comment here. 7 second looks like problem in indexes (too long for access by index ant too short for transferring huge data to client).

INSERT command itself is always quick (if not slowed down by triggers) and does not get slower significantly with increasing number of rows. Identity framework is probably running some SELECT (e.g. to re-read new line...?). Having indexes on all affected columns is not enough. Select command can use only ONE index on each table, so you need to find only ONE index, but the proper one - the correct combination of columns, column order in index is also important. And all this depends on the SQL command, that is the Identity engine trying to execute. Try to find it, then I can help you.